# Integrate array using scipy

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I am looking to find the area under a curve. The curve cannot be translated to an equation that is satisfactory. 
The coding is pretty straightforward.

```
from scipy.integrate import simps
import numpy as np
y =     np.array([1489.263705,1226.774401,5576.973322,1394.189836,1151.001948,867.5819289,773.5496598,1076.135273,1067.513122,3072.972271,2826.697242,1200.779848])
x =     np.array([40126,40154,40193,40226,40295,40325,40352,40379,40406,40448,40476,40490])
print simps(y,x)
```

Since my dataset isn't really that large, I tried doing it more manually in Excel. Once using the =FORECAST function and one time manually splitting it up in linear equations between different measuring points. 
The three different ways yield different results. 
=FORECAST (Value = 686.6569835 ) and manual splitting (678.9578851) is obvious - manual is better, it uses more points. 
The python way yields 662.425396.

Question 1 - What are the mathematics behind the discret integration - Surely it is linear, but how come then that it doesn't yield the same result?

Question 2 - Which result is most correct and why? I can integrate in several ways using scipy, how can I quantify which one is better without knowing the result?

Hope this question is not too off.

Best regards,
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Good intro is here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration

Question 2: If you do not know the curve (equation), it is hard to say what integration result is the best.

Comment: Thank you. I am aware of how integration works. I just wondered how integration would come around in this exact situation - eg. how the interpolation is done. Linear would be expected but the manual reult is different.

Comment: And yes - I know question 2 is hard, but I thought maybe someone knew some tricks with Bayesian Statistics. I thought about performing as many different integrations as possible and use the median value, but it only makes sense if the residuals are normal distributed and to know that I need to find a solid answer to question 1.